# Explain function returns in c

Tags: function, return, printf

Why do these message functions return the return value of the printf ?
I know this code should not be used, it was just out of curiosity

```
#include<stdio.h>
message1()
{
    printf("%d",(printf("Good")+printf("Morning")));
}

message2()
{
    printf("%d",printf("Good"),printf("Morning"));
}
 message3()
{
    printf("%d",(printf("Good"),printf("Morning")));
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",message1());
    printf("%d\n",message2());
    printf("%d\n",message3());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` returns the number of characters printed. Apart from that I have no idea what your question is

Comment: This wouldn't be valid C++. You may have more luck if you remove that tag.

Comment: You wrote them. You tell me.

Comment: Are you confusing writing output to a terminal with returned values of a function?

Comment: You should read a book or tutorial about C or C++ instead of writing random strings and give them to compiler. The C compiler is trustful that you know what you are doing and will accept a lot of stuff that a more dumb-proof compiler wouldn't, and even if you get the expected output it may be not because of the right reason, but out of sheer luck, so you should be careful of what you write. Study first, code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `message` functions lack a return type. C deduces it to be `int`. However, not returning a value from a non-void function is Undefined Behaviour.

In your case, the return value from `printf` has probably been stored in a register, which was not overwritten by `message` before it itself returned. Thus, the return value propagated.

While this can seem to ba all good and dandy, don't forget that UB is random by definition, and that you ought to avoid it at all cost (lest you want your program to mysteriously blow up when you change compiler / OS / Moon phase). Enabling (and acknowledging) compiler warnings would have saved you here.

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
message1()
{
    ...
}
```

The function is assumed to return an `int`. It is usually better to make it explicit:

```
int message1()
```

But your functions do not have any `return`, so the return value is *undefined*.

In your case, it happens that, by chance, the value stored as return value is the return value of the previous function call, that is `printf()`. But you should never trust in this.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed. The part you seem to be asking about then boils down to comparing these:

```
printf("%d", (4 + 7));
printf("%d", 4, 7);
printf("%d", (4, 7));
```

In the first one, `4 + 7` gives `11`. In the second one, `4` is printed and the excess argument is ignored (because no format specifier corresponds). In the third one , `(4, 7)` is an expression featuring the *comma operator* and so it evaluates to `7`.

NB. As everyone has pointed out, your code causes undefined behaviour by not returning a value from the function which returns `int`. You seem to be asking two different questions: why do your functions appear to return a value anyway; and what is the explanation of the other output you see.

The explanation of the first part is that it's undefined behaviour; to fix this you should change your functions to:

```
int message1(void)
{
    return printf("%d", (printf("Good")+printf("Morning")));
}
```

and so on (which I assume is what your intention was when you wrote the function).

Comment: I hope he's not really asking that, but probably why the return value of those function is the same as the inner printf even if he didn't write `return` on them

Comment: @pqnet your guess is as good as mine as to what the real question is

Comment: my guess is same as yours @MattMcNabb, so +1 :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb well, I don't think it is the same because the code he has shown is different. You are assuming he meant a different thing than what he wrote, which I did not.

Comment: @pqnet He said "why does the printf statement in last 2 functions give different outputs ?" which suggests that he wants to know the difference between his last 2 functions

Answer (score 0):

the functions you declared are implicitly declared as returning `int`. The compiler should warn you about that, and also tell you that it is deprecated: don't do deprecated stuff. Since you miss a `return` statement in them the return value is undefined. I guess you get the return value of `printf` because that's what is in the stack at that moment, in practice, just luck. You probably wouldn't have the same result if you defined a variable inside those functions.